# How to formalize Σ-algebras in Coq?

Tags: math, coq, dependent-type

A **signature** Σ is a set of function symbols where each symbol `f` is associated to an integer called the arity of `f`. Intuively, functions represented by a symbol `f` can only be applied to `arity(f)` arguments.

*Example* : Σ = {f/2, g/3}

Let Σ be a signature. A **Σ-algebra** is made of :

- a set `A`
- a mapping between function symbols of Σ to a function `(fA : A^n → A)` where `n` is the arity of the symbol `f`.

My problem is that I have some troubles formalizing these concepts (especially the arity of function symbols). I think I have to use dependent types but I'm not really familiar with them yet.

What I've tried so far :

```
Definition function_symbol := ascii.
Definition signature : Type := (list function_symbol) * arity.

Inductive sigma_term (sigma:signature) : Type :=
  | SigmaVar : variable -> sigma_term sigma
  | SigmaFunc f :
    let functions := fst sigma in
    let arity := snd sigma in
    In f functions -> ilist term (arity f) -> sigma_term sigma.

Definition sigma_algebra (sigma:signature) : Type :=
  let arity := snd sigma in
  {A : Type & forall f:function_symbol, nfun A (arity f) A}.
```

But it may be a bit over-complicated... I'm open to a better formalization.

**References** :

- [ilist (CPDT)](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/MoreDep.html)
- [nfun (Coq Standard Library)](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Numbers.NaryFunctions.html)
- [Universal Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra) where Σ-algebras are simply called algebras

Comment: This seems like it should be relevant: http://www-sop.inria.fr/lemme/Venanzio.Capretta/universal_algebra.html

Comment: @JohnColeman I saw it as well but I feel like I'm too far from understanding the definitions provided. I rather seek understanding, intuition more than practical use for educational purposes.

Comment: The first line of that link has: "The development is inspired by the presentation of Universal Algebra in the article by K. Meinke and J. V. Tucker in the Handbook of Logic in Computer Science.". If you could read this article then it might be easier to understand the thoughts that went into that development. I don't know really know `Coq` (although your question and that link makes me interested in it) so I can't say if anything much simpler is possible.

Comment: @JohnColeman Maybe I will take a look at it then. If you don't know Coq you should try as well. I'm sure you would love it as a mathematician and a computer scientist. Some classical references are [Software Foundations](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/index.html), [Adam Chipala's CPDT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/), [The Coq'Art](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540208549).

Comment: There are many ways to formalize the initial algebra (that is the syntax) and its associated interpretation. IMHO, it is hard to recommend one without knowing what your use case is going to be, as the tradeoffs will vary greatly.

Comment: @ejgallego Hm...I actually don't have any use case. So I think anything is fine.